# Render error render in error content area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-router-dom

const Pages = () => {

return (

```
<>

  <Box display="flex">

    {window.location.pathname === "/profile" ? undefined : <Sidebar />}

    <Box flex={3}>

      <Navbar />

      <Routes>

        {/* Content Area */}
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route exact path="/calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
        <Route exact path="/task" element={<div>Task</div>} />
        <Route exact path="/projects" element={<div>Projects</div>} />
        <Route exact path="/teamMember" element={<div>Team Member</div>} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        {/* Error Path */}
        <Route path="*" element={<div>404</div>} />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  </Box>

</>
```

);
};`enter code here`
[Hello, where do I put my error path because when it renders, it renders on my content area?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYLes.png)

Comment: What is the "content area"? Can you more clearly describe what the issue is and what you are expecting to see versus what you *actually* see?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you continually render a layout(Box, Sidebar, Navbar). There are a few options in order to achieve your request you have to either:

- create a Layout component that will render Box, Sidebar, and Navbar inside and use that `Layout` inside your pages, for example:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    // ...
    return (
        <Layout>
            Dashboard content
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

- or use the benefit of the new latest react-router package:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <Box display="flex">
            {window.location.pathname === "/profile" ? undefined : <Sidebar />}
            <Box flex={3}>
            <Navbar />
            <Outlet /> {/* Roughly speaking this is `children`. Refer to the documentation */}
        </Box>
    )
}

<Routes>
    <Route element={<Layout />} path="/">
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
        <Route path="/task" element={<div>Task</div>} />
        <Route path="/projects" element={<div>Projects</div>} />
        <Route path="/teamMember" element={<div>Team Member</div>} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<div>404</div>} />
</Routes>
```